# Instant Search using google api with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, google-api

I had been working on instant search in PHP using google jquery API .
In a youtube video this program is working (because i am learning from that video) .
My database logic is correct because i tried it in simple html page. 
But it not working on jquery. Please give me some suggestion to shot out this problem.
I am working on ubuntu 14.04.

This is my jquery contained PHP page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>WebPage</title>
    <script type=text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
    function searchq() {     
            var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
            $.post('search.php', {search_term: searchTxt}, function(output){
                    $('#output').html(output);
            }); 
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <b> First Name: </b> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search1" placeholder="Search for members ..." onkeydown="searchq();">
            <br/> <br/> <b> Submit: </b>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
```

My date connectivity page is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>WebPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
            $output = "Search Results. <br/> <br/>";
            if(isset($_POST["search_term"])){
                    $name = $_POST["search_term"];
                    $sql = "SELECT cust_id, last_name, first_name, email FROM widget_corp.customer WHERE first_name LIKE '%"
                            . $name . "%' OR last_name LIKE '%" . $name . "%'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if($count == 0){
                            echo "There were no search results.";
                    }
                    else {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                    $firstName = $row["first_name"] . "  ";
                                    $lastName =  $row["last_name"] . "  ";
                                    $Email = $row["email"] ;
                                    $output .= '<div>'.$firstName.' '.$lastName.'</div>';
                            }
                    }
            }
            echo ($output);
    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: What do you mean `doesnt work` does it say no results, not make an ajax request, something else? Watch the request in the developer tools of your browser and see what happens with the request..

Comment: Like so often asked and answered before, the elements you are targeting aren't found by jquery because your code is in the head, without document ready. Put the js right in front of the closing body tag

Comment: @chris85 doesnt  work   means that their is no instant search are available.

Comment: @Michael it is not working even if when i put the <script> tag in front of closing body tag.

Comment: Where is function `searchq`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add searchq function declaration but now i updated the function and it not working anyway.